# Macbook Pro temp at ~90℃ while gaming, what to do?

Tags: macbook-pro, cooling

My 2019 base MBP runs at 85-90℃ while playing the game "bad north" which is a simple game, it used to run alright in the past days (at ~60℃)

Today, It keeps jumping to 85-90℃ and sometimes the game just becomes unplayable. The fans are also running at max (7200rpm) the whole time the game is open.

I tried closing all other applications and even turning off Wi-Fi & Bluetooth, not to mention lowering the game's graphics, but it keeps happening... Do I need a cooling pad to game a bit?

Comment: Are you running on mains power? If so, try plugging your power cable in the other side.

Comment: The power cable is almost always plugged in, especially when playing.

Comment: So see what happens if you plug it in the other side...

Comment: There are only 2 thunderbolt ports, they're both on the left side, I'll check later to see if plugging into the other one would make it different (I plug randomly)

Comment: hmm, OK, I thought they all had connectors both sides these days. My bad.

Comment: @Tetsujin sounds like he has a 13".  15" MBP have ports on both sides. 2019 13" models only had ports on one side.

Comment: @Similari7ies See Activity Monitor > CPU tab, memory tab and Activity Monitor > Window Menu > GPU history.

If they're blasting, CPU usage is over 100%, memory pressure is high, or GPU is constantly busy, then the temperature is expected. 

Best you can do is not keep it on a cushion, rather a flat surface with nothing behind it.

Comment: @ankii after some testing, CPU usage never exceeded 20% and memory pressure was the same, GPU history did spike up though, temps were at ~75℃ at max rpm.